# Are there any possible complications when calculating capital gain while trading gold ETR, compared to regular ETFs?

Tags: canada, etf, capital-gains-tax, gold

In particular, is MNT.TO ETR treated any different from ETFs when calculating ACB? I assume that it pays no dividends, and thus buy/sell would be the only taxable events, or am I missing anything? I am contemplating DCA into it over the next year, but don't to face too many complications since I plan on doing it in an unregistered account.